# Contact Form Returning 409 Error PHP JavaScript HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, email

I have a contact form on my personal website for the past few days and I ran into a problem that Google Chrome's Developer Console marks as error 409, as far as I know a error 409 can be caused by a series of issues such as:

1. Conflict between ID's (doesn't seem to be the problem)
2. Conflict problem with the server (I talked with HostGator customer support and no issues were found)
3. Conflict between code communication (I think this is the issue)

When I run the .php code by accessing it through my website /main.php, I am able to receive an empty email, which could probably mean that the communication between the files, JavaScript, PHP and HTML are not properly communicating which is my best bet. I can't seem to find whats causing the error.

Code on CodePen (NOTE: PHP is commented out on the javascript snippet)

https://codepen.io/jpgaviria/pen/WNKpyGV

HTML

```html
<div class="col-lg-7">
  <div class="form-contact">
    <form action="#" id="formcontact">
      <div class="form-group row formwrap">
        <div class="col-lg-6 pt-5">
          <label for="yourname">Nombre</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="yourname"
            placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre"
            name="name"
            class="mt-3 input-control inputtext"
            data-name="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 pt-5">
          <label for="yourmail">E-Mail</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="yourmail"
            placeholder="Ingresa tu e-mail"
            name="email"
            class="mt-3 input-control inputtext"
            data-name="email"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 pt-5">
          <label for="comment">Mensaje</label>
          <textarea
            class="comentarea mt-3 input-control"
            id="comment"
            placeholder="Tienes una campaña en mente? Descríbenos como la visualizas y cuales son tus metas, así podemos ayudarte."
            data-name="comment"
            name="comment"
          ></textarea>
          <button
            id="submitbutton"
            class="submitbuton button mt-5 mb-3"
            type="submit"
          >
            Enviar Ahora
          </button>
          <div class="contactform__loader pt-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```php
<?php
$subject    = 'E-mail from' . $_REQUEST['email']; // Subject of your email
$to         = 'e-mail@example.com'; //Your e-mail address
$headers    = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
              'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$message    = 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . ' <br/>' .
              'E-mail: ' . $_REQUEST['email'] . ' <br/>' .
              'Message: ' . $_REQUEST['comment'];
if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
 echo 'your message send';
}
else
{
 echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

JS:

```js
/*
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version       : 1.1
Filename      : main.js
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
const rushinit = (function() {
    "use strict";
    // variable 
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    var header = document.getElementById('wrap-header');
    var wrapload = document.querySelector('.loading');
    var glass = document.querySelector('.glasseffect');
    var GL = document.querySelectorAll(".gl");
    var menubar = document.querySelector('.menu-bar');
    var closemenu = document.querySelector('.wrap-close')
    var mobilenav = document.querySelector('.mobile-navwrap');
    var mobilelink = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation-listmobile li a');
    var testimonials = document.getElementById("wrap-testimonial");
    var buttonsubmit = document.getElementById('submitbutton');
    var formcontact = document.getElementById('formcontact');
    var allinputs = formcontact.querySelectorAll('.input-control');
    var information = document.querySelector('.contactform__loader');
    var inputelement = document.querySelector('.inputtext');
    var textareaelement = document.querySelector('.comentarea');
    // glass effect on desktop this will not work on firefox
    var glassx = true;
    // glass effect on mobile this will not work on firefox
    var glassonmobile = true;
    //detect mobile device
    var isMobile = {
        Android: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
        BlackBerry: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
        iOS: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
        Opera: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
        },
        Windows: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
        },
        any: function() {
            return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
        }
    };
    // loader page
    const loadder = function(e) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            fadeOut(wrapload)
        }, 1000);
    };
    // testimonial slider 
    const testimonialslider = function(e) {
        new KeenSlider(testimonials, {
            loop: true,
            mode: "free-snap",
            breakpoints: {
                "(min-width: 320px)": {
                    slides: { perView: 1, spacing: 5 },
                },
                "(min-width: 400px)": {
                    slides: { perView: 1, spacing: 5 },
                },
                "(min-width: 1000px)": {
                    slides: { perView: 1, spacing: 20 },
                },
            },
            slides: {
                perView: 2,
                spacing: 15,
            }
        });
    };
    // titlt image 
    const tiltinit = function(e) {
        VanillaTilt.init(GL, {
            max: 10,
            speed: 400
        });
    };
    //fade in effect
    const fadeIn = function(el) {
        el.classList.add('show');
        el.classList.remove('hide');
    };
    //fade out effect
    const fadeOut = function(el) {
        el.classList.add('hide');
        el.classList.remove('show');
    };
    // form post submit  
    const posttheform = function(e) {
        formcontact.onsubmit = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            var valid = [];
            allinputs.forEach(function(i, j) {
                if (i.getAttribute('data-name')) {
                    var checkAttr = i.getAttribute('data-name');
                } else {
                    var checkAttr = i.tagName;
                }
                var thisvalue = i.value;
                // check input valid
                switch (checkAttr) {
                    case 'name':
                        if (thisvalue == '') {
                            i.classList.add("error");
                            valid.push('<li>Please check your input name</li>');
                        } else if (thisvalue.length < 3) {
                            valid.push('<li>Sorry your name char is to short</li>');
                        } else {
                            i.classList.remove("error");
                        }

                        break;
                    case 'email':
                        var regEmail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
                        if (i.value == '' || !regEmail.test(i.value)) {
                            i.classList.add("error");
                            valid.push('<li>Please check your mail address input</li>');
                        } else {
                            i.classList.remove("error");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'comment':
                        if (thisvalue == '') {
                            i.classList.add("error");
                            valid.push('<li>Please write something</li>');
                        } else {
                            i.classList.remove("error");
                        }

                        break;
                    default:
                        if (i.value == '') {
                            valid.push('<li>Something was wrong</li>');
                            i.classList.add("error");
                        } else {
                            i.classList.remove("error");
                        }
                        break;
                };
            });
            if (valid.length) {
                information.innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><h4 class="alert-heading">There is something wrong !</h4> <hr><p class="mb-0"><ul class="errorlist">` + valid.join('') + `</ul></p></div>`;
            } else {
                information.innerHTML = `<div class="d-flex align-items-center"><strong class="font-weight-normal">Please wait...</strong><div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm ml-auto" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></div></div>`;
                inputelement.setAttribute("readonly", "true");
                textareaelement.setAttribute("readonly", "true");
                buttonsubmit.setAttribute("disable", "true");
                // change the fetch address based on the mail.php file you put in your server's file directory ---------------------------
                let response = await fetch('mail.php', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: new FormData(formcontact)
                    })
                    .then((response) => response.text())
                    //Then with the data from the response in JSON...
                    .then((data) => {
                        if (data === 'your message send') {
                            formcontact.reset();
                            inputelement.removeAttribute("readonly");
                            textareaelement.removeAttribute("readonly");
                            buttonsubmit.removeAttribute("disable");
                            information.innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-success  " role="alert"><h4 class="alert-heading">Message send successful !</h4> <hr><p class="mb-0">I will reply to your message soon thank you</p></div>`;
                        }
                    })
                    //Then with the error genereted...
                    .catch((error) => {
                        formcontact.reset();
                        inputelement.removeAttribute("readonly");
                        textareaelement.removeAttribute("readonly");
                        buttonsubmit.removeAttribute("disable");
                        information.innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-danger " role="alert"><h4 class="alert-heading">There is something wrong !</h4> <hr><p class="mb-0">Sorry, your message failed to be sent due to an unknown error</p></div>`;
                    });
            }
            return false;
        };
    };
    // click button menu burger
    const buttonclick = function(e) {
        // menu mobile toggle
        menubar.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            //your handler here 
            this.style.display = 'none';
            mobilenav.style.display = 'block';
            mobilenav.classList.remove('closemenu');
            mobilenav.classList.add('showmenu');
            closemenu.style.display = 'block';
            body.classList.add('fixed');
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
        //close menu 
        closemenu.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            this.style.display = 'none';
            mobilenav.classList.remove('showmenu');
            mobilenav.classList.add('closemenu');
            body.classList.remove('fixed');
            menubar.style.display = 'block';
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
        // mobile link navigation 
        for (var i = 0; i < mobilelink.length; i++) {
            mobilelink[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                closemenu.style.display = 'none';
                mobilenav.classList.remove('showmenu');
                mobilenav.classList.add('closemenu');
                body.classList.remove('fixed');
                menubar.style.display = 'block';
            }, false);
        };
    };
    //binds event ----------------------------
    const bindEvents = function(e) {
        // window onbuffer
        window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
            // force scroll to top when refresh page
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        };
        // window load
        window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
            //load animation page 
            loadder();
        });
        // document load
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
            // menu 
            buttonclick();
            // scroll spy 
            new bootstrap.ScrollSpy(document.body, {
                target: '*',
                offset: 1
            });
            //init if not on mobile 
            if (!isMobile.any()) {
                tiltinit();
            };
            //slider
            testimonialslider();
            // GLightbox 
            GLightbox();
            // animated on scroll
            AOS.init({
                disable: function() {
                    var maxWidth = 999;
                    return window.innerWidth < maxWidth;
                },
                once: false
            });
            // post contact 
            posttheform();
        });
        window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
            if (window.pageYOffset > 10) {
                header.classList.add('fixi');
            } else {
                header.classList.remove('fixi');
            };
        });
        window.addEventListener("activate.bs.scrollspy", (e) => {
            // let links = navlinks.classList.contains('active');
            var index = document.querySelector('nav a.active').getAttribute('href');
            if (index == '#home') {
                fadeOut(glass);
            };
            if (isMobile.any()) {
                if (glassonmobile) {
                    // comment this line if dont want any glass blur effect
                    if (index == '#home') {
                        fadeOut(glass);
                    } else {
                        fadeIn(glass);
                    }
                };
            };
            if (!isMobile.any()) {
                if (glassx) {
                    // comment this line if dont want any glass blur effect
                    if (index == '#home' || index == '#contact-section') {
                        fadeOut(glass);
                    } else {
                        fadeIn(glass);
                    }
                };
            };
        });
    };
    // init - initilizes elements and events
    const Init = function(e) {
        bindEvents();
    };
    return {
        Init: Init
    };
}());
//initilizing app
rushinit.Init();
```

Comment: Is all that javascript relevant to the problem at hand? Please consider a [MCVE]

Comment: I am running into a similar issue (409 conflict) on my hosted website using phpmailer for a form. Was working fine until hoster upgraded from 7.3/4 to php 8.0.27. I updated the phpmailer version with no change.  I am using jquery 1.9 with ajax and I have read it may need to be upgraded. HTH.